# MVC3 EF Code First - JQuery IU Datapicker error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a problem in my mvc3 app when i choose a date past day 12 from a datepicker the controller gets the default date of datetime "1/01/0001"

heres my model

```
    public virtual int ID { set; get; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Cantidad de CD4")]
    [Range(400,1200, ErrorMessage="La cantidad de CD4 debe estar entre 400 y 1200")]
    public virtual int Cantidad_CD4 { set; get; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Fecha { set; get; }
```

my view 
    @model PacientMVC.Models.CD4

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
```

`

### Create

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>CD4</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cantidad_CD4)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cantidad_CD4)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cantidad_CD4)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fecha)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fecha)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fecha)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") 
</div>`
```

and then my method of the controller

```
     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(int pacientID, CD4 newCD4)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            var objpacient = _db.Pacients.Single(r => r.ID == pacientID);
            objpacient.CD4S.Add(newCD4);
            _db.SaveChanges();



            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Pacient", new { id = pacientID });
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}",     validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }

            return View();
        }


        //}
        //catch
        //{
        //    return View();
        //}
    }
```

and i make my jquery like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });

});
```

and i make the following template for DATETIME

```
@model  System.DateTime     


@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { @class = "date" })
```

I am from Spain (and noob in MVC) so we used the date in the following format: dd/mm/yyyy

I think he believes that i use the date like US mm/dd/yyyy

the error is a dbentityvalidationexception in _db.SaveChanges();

i dont know where i have to make the changes

sorry for my bad English please help me

Answer (score 0):

it looks indeed like a globalization issue..

try to add this to your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="es-ES" uiCulture="es-ES" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

that might just work :)

Scott Hanselman wrote an extensive blog post about this:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx
There are also examples about the DatePicker with globalization.

---

On a sidenote: you should also use `ModelState.IsValid` before saving your entity to the database.